# Defining an integer for last row in column

Tags: excel, vba, variables, runtime-error, row

I'm getting Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error on the following code (where I define lr) and cannot for the life of me work out the problem.

The aim of the code is to search for a matching Project Description in column defined as "ProjectDescriptionColumn", and to return a Project Code that lives in the cell of the same row but in column defined as "ProjectCodeColumn"

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Dim ProjectDescriptionColumn As Long
Dim ProjectCodeColumn As Long

With Sheets("Completed")
If Cells(LastRowInL, "M").Value = "Engine Ancillaries" Then ProjectDescriptionColumn = 8 And ProjectCodeColumn = 9
End With

Dim lr As Integer
Dim i As Integer

lr = Sheets("VBA_Data").Cells(1, ProjectDescriptionColumn).End(xlDown).Row '<<<Run-time error here>>>

For i = 1 To lr

If UCase(Range(Sheets("Completed").Cells(LastRowInL, "B")).Value) = UCase(Sheets("VBA_Data").Cells(i, ProjectDescriptionColumn).Value) Then
Range(Sheets("Completed").Cells(LastRowInL, "N")).Value = Sheets("VBA_Data").Cells(i, ProjectCodeColumn).Value
End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the If statement isn't true, the column variables are never set.   For me, that creates an index error, not a 1004.   But a run-time error is surely related to the values plugged into the statement at the time.   Can you step through the code to that point, and check the value of ProjectDescriptionColumn ?